# What are data formatters and http protocols? When we should use them?

Tags: json, xml, web-services, client-server, odata

What are the data formatters and http protocols?

I am somewhat confused about the below terms:

1.ODATA
2.REST and SOAP
3.WCF services
4.XML web services
5. JSON
6. WSDL

Answer (score 1):

REST - A style of web services.

JSON - JavaScript Object Notation - basically, a concise way of serializing objects.

SOAP - An XML format used to do web service calls

WCF Services - a Microsoft framework for making web services.

WSDL - Web Service Description Language. Usually used to automatically discover information about a web service, generate proxies, etc. - typically used with SOAP-based services.

OData - standard protocol/format for calling RESTful web services

The HTTP Protocol is at a somewhat lower level than these protocols are - it's a general [application-level protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) that's used for making requests and responses in general. It's more about how you do a request to a server (and what it'll send back) in general, whereas things like OData and SOAP dictate what you actually put in the request and response. Does that make sense?

Comment: which one is  HTTP Protocals?

Comment: @adilahmed See my edit, hopefully that clarifies things a little bit.

Comment: thanks,can you provide a realtime example and usage where to use these (ODATA and SOAP)